# How to specify certain class from same named classes of two different libraries?

Tags: syntax, dart, flutter

```
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
```

Both of the imports above have classes named `Path` and I need a way to distinguish between them since I need to use both in the same dart file.

Is there a syntax to specifically point to which `Path` I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:ui' hide Path;
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

Then when you use `Path`, it's used from `latlong` and if you use `ui.Path` the one from `dart:ui` is used.

This line can be omitted

```
import 'dart:ui' hide Path;
```

but it allows you to use all other types from `dart:ui` without the `ui.` prefix.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick and perfect explanation. Golden information:)